# Node Promise not worth waiting for

Tags: node.js, typescript, es6-promise

So trying my best to get my head around streams, promise and async functions in node. I never seem to get it right. I have a couple of use cases (and it seems very standard) that is very similar. Something like this:

1. I have a stream that gets some data
2. I need to pipe it to a process(fast-csv in this case)
3. Once it has completed, I need to send it to the next step (in the real case, to a database)
4. In a real world scenario, I need to wait for the database update to complete
5. Next open next file stream
6. Process
7. Add
8. Repeat ...

So the below code "SHOULD" do just that, but the promise will not wait to be resolved. Await only works in async functions (and streams seems to actively ignore any attempts to use await)

```
import { parseString } from '@fast-csv/parse';
import * as fs from "fs";

async function IHateStreams (){
    /** Lets read profiles */
    console.log("1: Reading Program " + profileFS);
    let fileContent = fs.readFileSync(profileFS, 'utf8');
    let dataset : Array<any> = []
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        parseString(fileContent, {headers: true})
            .on('error', error => console.error(error))
            .on('data', row => dataset.push(row))
            .on('end',  () {
                console.log("2: Inside Done")
                resolve
            });
    })

}

IHateStreams().then(console.log("3: stream done!"));
console.log("4: code done, so running next command with the data")
```

Instead of a nice output:

```
1: Reading Program ./dbinitdata/ProfileIdName.csv
2: Inside Done
3: stream done!
4: code done
```

I get:

```
1: Reading Program ./dbinitdata/ProfileIdName.csv 
3: stream done! 
4: code done 
2: Inside Done
```

Comment: You don't seem to *call* resolve, for one thing. `3` isn't actually in a *callback* to `.then`, so you're passing the result of logging to `.then` and `4` isn't part of the promise chain at all.

Comment: I'm OK with me getting it wrong, but I don't know what I am missing. I accept your comment on 4, but it was the easiest way I could think of to show flow of event. But please help me out here, how do I get a simple promise to get some code to wait until the end event working?

Comment: TypeScript will be able to help you with some of it - when I try to run your code with `ts-node` I get told that `profileFS` isn't defined, that your `on("end"` callback is malformed and that `.then(console.log("3: stream done!"))` doesn't make sense (as noted above). Fixing those and *calling* resolve at least gets 1, 2 and 3 in the right order.

Comment: Thank you very much, had not understood .then, finally got await to work with the promise, so at last it is working the way I wanted. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all the faffing about, I was so close. The code above fails because of 3 reasons. (If anyone has been on my journey)

Wrap in promise seems to work, the problem with the above was:

1. Forget `.then()` thing that is specific to streams
2. Typos will not get you anywhere, `resolve()`
3. For the purpose I needed it for, (not an architect), create a `async` control function and let that pretend that all is sequential by kicking of stream after stream wrapped in a promise.

There are probably easier smother ways to do it, but hopefully, this shines some light.

```
import { parseString } from '@fast-csv/parse';
import * as fs from "fs";

 const profileFS: string = "tsconfig.json"

async function IHateStreams (){
    /** Lets read profiles */
    console.log("1: Reading Program " + profileFS);
    let fileContent = fs.readFileSync(profileFS, 'utf8');
    let dataset : Array<any> = []
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        parseString(fileContent, {headers: true})
            .on('error', error => console.error(error))
            .on('data', row => dataset.push(row))
            .on('end',  data => {
                console.log("2: Reading Program " + data);
                resolve();
            }
            });
    })

}
async function iWait (){
    const isThisAPromise = await IHateStreams()
    console.log("3: code done, so running next command with the data")
}

iWait();
console.log("1.99: code done, not in chain")
```

Comment: `.then` is *not* specific to streams, it's a method on promises (and other "thenables").

Comment: I'll try to get my head around the axles next week:)

Comment: What axles? Please at least correct the information in your answer.